# How do a date delimited query in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Previous to Meteor 0.5.5 I was able to do this.

```
var query = {};
var ts = new Date();
query.start_date = { $lte: ts };
query.end_date = { $gte: ts };
var result = Collection.find(query);
```

It used to return records.  Now it does not.

When I do a `console.log(query)` there is a `__proto__` on the query and on the `start_date` and `end_date`.

So, how do I do date delimited queries in Meteor now?

Comment: Could you try your query in the mongo shell and see if results are expected? I created gist.github.com/Tarangp/5094325 to test date queries with the latest version 0.57 and it looks like its the same

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to using moment.js.  This works.

```
var ts = moment().format();
```

Answer (score 0):

On meteor.js 0.5.7 I´m using this to delimite queries by dates with good results:

```
userLive.find({readedAt: {$gte: startDay, $lt: endDay}});
```

Comment: Are you setting startDate and endDay as = new Date().  That was the offending bit.